# 2nd Level Dynamic Scraping of a web page

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have an assignment where I have to scrape some parts of a web page. The web page given to me is the BSE India home page. I have to scrape the Trending Companies in News & Social Media section.

Each company has a link to a pop-up which has a graph and other things included. I need the graph and the right hand side column which gives the top 10 tweets for that company from the past 30 days. 
[The link shows the pop up for one of the companies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxFcm.png)

Since all of this data is dynamic, it is not explicitly shown in the source of the HTML page. 
https://www.bseindia.com/ is the website link and the section is the left section in the second part of the web page. How do I go about doing this?

I tried going through a loop and opening each link by clicking the company row. After that I am not understanding how to get the data. While inspecting the page, I saw that the frame is an iframe which is different than the first one, so I tried to change that. But that gives me an exception saying that the frame is not located. Also, I am not understanding how to go back to the previous frame after closing the pop up.

The following code gets all the company names and the percentage. I need to get into each company's pop-up and get all the information according to my requirement.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

co = []
percentage = []
files = []

mydriver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files/chromedriver.exe')
mydriver.get("https://www.bseindia.com/")
time.sleep(10) # wait 5 seconds until DOM will load completely
iframe = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class = 'sentifi-widget-frame']") # locate iframe element
mydriver.switch_to.frame(iframe) # switch to the iframe

for count in range(1,11):
    co_name = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'sf-widget-wrapper']/div/div/div/div/div/div[" + str(count) + "]/span/span[@class = 'sf-topic-name-text']") 
    co.append(co_name.text)

    co_percentage = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'sf-widget-wrapper']/div/div/div/div/div/div[" + str(count) + "]/div/span/span[@class = 'sf-percent-number']") 
    percentage.append(co_percentage.text)

    file = "file_"+str(count)+".xlsx"
    files.append(file)

t = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'sf-widget-wrapper']/div/div/div/div/div/span[@class = 'sf-updated-time']") 
t_t = [t.text]
for i in range(1,10):
    t_t.append("")

mydriver.switch_to_default_content()
mydriver.close()
mydriver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Company Name':co, 'Percentage':percentage, 'Files': files, 'Update' : t_t})
df.to_excel('Trending Companies.xlsx', header=True, index=False) #print the data in the excel sheet.
```

The files written in the file list should include the information of each company, ie. the graph and the list of tweets. 
[The excel file after the 1st level scrape.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhauJ.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please post your code here.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will fetch you the individual company links:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

mydriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files/chromedriver.exe' , chrome_options=chrome_options)
mydriver.get("https://www.bseindia.com/")

WebDriverWait(mydriver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "sentifi-widget-frame")))

iframe = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class = 'sentifi-widget-frame']") # locate iframe element
mydriver.switch_to.frame(iframe) # switch to the iframe

for count in range(1,11):

    selector = "#sf-widget-wrapper > div > div > div > div > div.sf-widget-content > div:nth-child(" + str(count) + ") > span.sf-topic-name > span"
    WebDriverWait(mydriver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
    companyElement = mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
    companyElement.click()

    mydriver.switch_to_default_content()
    newiFrame =  mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#SF-Screen-ranking-914SF2-EN")
    mydriver.switch_to.frame(newiFrame)

    WebDriverWait(mydriver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sf-header-anchor")))
    href = mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sf-header-anchor").get_attribute("href")
    print("Company Link " + str(count) + " : " + href)

    closePopUp = mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector(".icon.sfin-close")
    closePopUp.click()

    mydriver.switch_to_default_content()
    mydriver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

mydriver.switch_to_default_content()
mydriver.close()
mydriver.quit()
```

Sample Output:

```
Company Link 1 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/vikas-ecotech
Company Link 2 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/nbcc-india
Company Link 3 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/interglobe-aviation
Company Link 4 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/tata-motors-ltd
Company Link 5 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/iifl-holdings
Company Link 6 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/idbi-bank-ltd
Company Link 7 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/nhpc
Company Link 8 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/hdfc-ltd
Company Link 9 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/hindustan-copper
Company Link 10 : https://sentifi.com/stocks/krbl-ltd
```

---

**Additional:**

If you keenly observe the XHR URL's, then this request gives you the individual company links. `https://widgets.sentifi.com/boards?portfolioId=96330&period=lastweek&top=2&order=topicBuzzChange&language=en&eventStatisticLanguage=en&eventStatisticEnable=false`

*If you modify the "top" parameter in the XHR URL from 2 to 10, then we will get the top 10 trending companies*.

Sample JSON response for top 2 companies:

```
{
  "type": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "itemkey": 1798045,
      "name": "Vikas EcoTech",
      "shortName": "Vikas EcoTech",
      "listedCompany": true,
      "buzz": null,
      "channels": null,
      "avg30h": null,
      "change": 250,
      "urn": "/stocks/vikas-ecotech",
      "hasNewEvent": null,
      "isin": "INE806A01020"
    },
    {
      "itemkey": 25075,
      "name": "NBCC (India)",
      "shortName": "NBCC India",
      "listedCompany": true,
      "buzz": null,
      "channels": null,
      "avg30h": null,
      "change": 160,
      "urn": "/stocks/nbcc-india",
      "hasNewEvent": null,
      "isin": "INE095N01023"
    }
  ],
  "extra": {
    "updatedTime": "2018-06-25T12:11:15.776Z"
  },
  "error": 0,
  "message": null,
  "localization": null,
  "params": null,
  "pager": null
}
```